# How does Laravel Contracts work

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I want to destroy a record,I only use the code like below

*route*

```
Route::resource('link-submit', 'LinkSubmitController', ['except' => ['show']]);
```

*action*

```
public function destroy(LinkSubmit $linkSubmit)
{
    if ($linkSubmit->delete()) {
        $key = 'ok_message';
        $message = 'delete ok';
    } else {
        $key = 'error_message';
        $message = 'delete fail';
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with($key, $message);
}
```

I found that when I use `$link` instead of `$linkSubmit`,it will not work.
How Laravel get the parameters? Which file is the code in , I'm confused

Comment: Please explain details what do you want?

Comment: How do Laravel implement the `LinkSubmit $linkSubmit` auto assign the recored to it,I am very confused which file the php code in.

Comment: If the question is how Laravel knows what class instance to provide to the destroy method, then read about the [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container). If you only replaced $linkSubmit with $link in the destroy method definition, then it fails, because you call delete() on an undefined variable $linkSubmit.